# How to find the threshold that maximizes the F1 score?

Tags: classification, optimization, threshold

I have a probabilistic, binary classifier. Is there any principled way to select the threshold that maximizes the F1 score? Currently I simply choose many different thresholds, apply them on some validation data and pick the threshold that yields the highest F1 score.